# Configuring NAT and static IP on Cisco 877W

Tags: cisco, dhcp, nat, adsl

I'm having trouble setting up a static IP reservation on a network. What I want to do is assign IP 192.168.1.105 to MAC address 00:21:5d:2f:58:04 and then port forward 35394 to it.

If it helps, output from show ver says Cisco IOS software, C870 software (C870-ADVSECURITYK9-M), version 12.4(4)T7, release software (fc1)
ROM: System bootstrap, version 12.3(8r)YI4, release software

I have done this -

```
service dhcp
ip routing
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.99
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.200 192.168.1.255

ip dhcp pool ClientDHCP
network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.1.1
dns-server 192.168.1.1
lease 7

ip dhcp pool NEO
host 192.168.1.105 255.255.255.0
hardware-address 0021.5D2F.5804

ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.105 35394 <PUBLIC_IP> 35394 extendable
```

However, the machine is getting assigned IP address 192.168.1.101 not .105 ... any suggestions?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
hardware-address 0021.5D2F.5804 ieee802
```

note the "ieee802" ... take a look [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_0t/12_0t1/feature/guide/Easyip2.html#wp6991)

Comment: Thanks, I modified the command to add ieee802, then wrote the config back and did an ipconfig/release / ipconfig/renew on the computer in question. Unfortunately it's still getting .101 - but maybe that's because it's picking up the existing lease? Can I flush the existing DHCP allocations somehow?

Comment: Yay, clear ip dhcp binding 192.168.1.101 followed by ipconfig /release / ipconfig /renew has worked. Thanks!